# Is it possible to assign a value to a const Variable when creating an Object?

Tags: c#

I am creating a Client for a WebRequestTool which contains a Token that is used throughout the lifetime of each Object but is unique to each entity of the class. Since I do not want that value to be changeable after an Object is created, I would like it to be Constant.

I already tried using an internal SetMethod which is called from the constructor like :

```
internal void setToken(string token)
{
    this.TOKEN = token; 
}
```

I also tried just assigning it inside the constructor. That is also not working.

```
public class Client
{
    const TOKEN; 

    public client(string token)
    {
      this.TOKEN = token;
    }
}
```

Is there really no other way of assigning a constant than hardcoding it when declaring it? And if there is what is it ?

Comment: How about using [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly)?

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about that since I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const):

> A const field can only be initialized at the declaration of the field

You might want to use [readonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) instead:

> A readonly field can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor. Therefore, readonly fields can have different values depending on the constructor used

Another nice resource: [Difference between readonly and const keyword in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-readonly-and-const-keyword-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: Is there a way to do all that from a Set Function? Since readonly also seems to only be writable from the constructor.

Comment: @ArtisticAligator - like from a setter? Is your case that you do not know when you want to initialize it but that you want only once?

Comment: No that would not be because of the time I want to set it but because of keeping the size of the constructor comprehensible.

Comment: @ArtisticAligator what do you mean by "keeping the size of the constructor comprehensible"?

Comment: Well it's getting really huge with all the assignments I have to do so I thought that might be a valid idea. Is it not?

Comment: @ArtisticAligator - if it is big it is probably doing too much. Think if you could use multiple ctors where one calls another. If not then you could also create some private functions and call them from the ctor. Still I'd say that if the ctor is doing so much it is probably doing stuff it shouldn't

Comment: Alright. I didn't even think about multiple ctors thanks ! I'll also see what I can cut to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can insted declare it private readonly

```
public class Client
{
   private readonly string _token;

   public Client(string token)
   {
       _token = token;
   }
}
```

Readonly fields can't be modified once they are set and can be set in the constructor.